# Route traffic from WIndows to Linux(Kali)

Tags: linux, windows, networking, proxy, routes

I'm currently trying to route my internet traffic from my Windows laptop(192.168.1.73) to my other laptop running Kali Linux(192.168.1.64), both on the same network. The idea is the Linux laptop would anonymise the traffic sent, possibly hiding my IP in some way. I'm stuck on how to exactly go about this. I've tried using OpenVPN but to no avail.

Comment: You don't need any routing for that and certainly no VPN. Both systems are on the same network unless you implemented some very exotic setup. Just connect.

Comment: How exactly would you recommend i connect to my linux laptop from windows?

Comment: I am sorry, I just now understood your question! My bad.

Comment: How is that MS-Windows system connected to the Internet? I read your question such that the MS-Windows system has an internet connection and the Linux box does not... Or is it the other way round? Still the first question remains... What connection do you have?

Comment: Both have internet connection. Both via Wifi.

Comment: Then why do you want to route any internet traffic? Please tell what exactly you are trying to do. Thanks. Use the `edit` button below your question for that instead of posting comments. Thanks!

Comment: The linux laptop can anonymise traffic. I forgot to update my question sorry. Updated now.

Comment: You cannot hide your IP address to the outside world, since you have to receive traffic back to that IP. No idea what you mean by "anonymise" here, but I understand that you want to route traffic through the Linux box. That means you have to reconfigure the network stack on the MS-Windows system to use the Linux box (its internal IP address) as a gateway (for the routing). And you have to modify the IP stack ("firewall") on the Linux box such that it forwards the packages sent by the MS-Windows system to the internet. Where the anonymization steps in depends on how that stuff actually works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112720/discussion-between-snazzywolf-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.x is not public IP subnet. So both your computers are in local net. And so one or both have yet default gateway address for access to Internet and another networks. If you want route Internet traffic through the Windows Laptop to Linux computer you have to setup the Windows IP address like default gateway for Linux computer. 
Then on Windows you can used two options for access to Internet for Linux:
1. enabled routing functions use Windows like just router
2. used third party software (like Wingate etc) use Windows like NAT proxy

In the first option the Linux IP address will be view at ISP devices 
In the second option the Linux IP address will be change on Windows IP adress

The first is very simple for management. The second is harder.

But I don't understood why it all. If you wanna more security in Internet network you can use https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Download and get maximum security level.

Answer (score 0):

I'd honestly trash this idea and use Tor browser instead, you will be 100% anonymous if you follow the guidelines on their website.

The Tor project:
https://www.torproject.org/

Tips on staying anonymous:
https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en#stayinganonymous

Well and if you seriously want to route the traffic to your Kali machine, use some built-in MITM tools (eg. Arpspoof), but be aware, that this will NOT make you anonymous to the outside (Internet).

Here is how you set-up the MITM, but without the intercepting of traffic:

First, we need to forward all the trafic that the Kali machine recieves to the internet

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then you need to send the forged ARP replies

```
arpspoof -i [Network Interface Name] -t [Windows IP] [Router IP]
```

So it should look something like this, you can find the router ip by running the command ifconfig (look for "default gateway")

```
arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.73 192.168.1.1
```

Then it should be up and running, tunneling you through the Kali machine.